# How to change SWT Tree plus/minus icons

Tags: java, treeview, swt

I am working on a SWT Tree similar to the one [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/CreateaSWTtreelazy.htm), however, I want to be able to show + signs in some cases instead of - for an expanded tree item. Is this possible ?

If not, is there Windows API to have custom icons for the expanded/collapsed state of a tree item ?

Comment: The solution is to use TVE_EXPANDPARTIAL message in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

The SWT Tree component makes use of native Tree widget if available, for example in case of Windows - it uses native widget while on Linux (depends on the UI engine being used), it may create custom tree on its own.

On the OS where it uses native Tree widget, it's not possible to customize the + and - icons.

As Ali suggested (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773568%28VS.85%29.aspx), you may wish to use `TVE_EXPANDPARTIAL`, but keep in mind that the code will be OS dependent (even within versions of Windows).

You may, however, wish you use a custom image - using `getImage()` method in the `TreeContentProvider` to indicate the otherwise rather than relying on `TVE_EXPANDPARTIAL`. This will also ensure that your code is OS independent.

Comment: Thanks! TreeContentProvider is not part of SWT though ... Not sure how you you would do it but you bring up a good point about the code having to be OS dependent. I ended up implementing a 64 bit version and a 32 bit version of SWTTree subclass.

Comment: Ah! I forgot... it's part of JFace. Related class is TreeViewer.

Comment: setImage doesn't actually change the +/- icon. It adds an image to the right of +/- icon.

Comment: Agree. It does not change +/- icon but can be used to give the user an indication about what's happening / about-to-happen / can-happen