# How can I stop the tree view expand/collapse icons from fading when losing focus in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Helios and have noticed that the treeview in the package explorer now auto-hides the expand/collapse tree icons when I move my focus away from it. I personally find this behavior a bit distracting and was wondering if anyone knows how to disable it?

Answer (score 3):

Introduced in Vista ([by design say this thread](http://www.vistax64.com/vista-file-management/39970-sub-directory-indicators-vanish-left-pane-explorer.html)), the sub-directory indicators now vanish when the tree is out of focus.
And the [superusers had only one global setting to prevent that](https://superuser.com/questions/9446/vista-tree-view-disabling-fade-out-of-tree-nodes).

> - Right click `Computer > Properties`
> - Advanced System Settings
> - Under Performance click Settings
> - Un-check **`Fade or Slide Menus into View`**
> - Apply

But that didn't prevent the fade effect in my Eclipse session (maybe a reboot is necessary?)

Since SWT Tree is base on the native OS widget ([`TreeView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759988(v=VS.85).aspx)), it will inherit its native graphic evolutions.
See for instance "[How to change SWT Tree plus/minus icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554504/how-to-change-swt-tree-plus-minus-icons)".

Comment: I found a similar question on Super User which also suggested this. Tried it and rebooted, but seemingly no effect on Eclipse or Explorer for that matter.

Comment: @Michael: I agree. It seems the SWT Tree use the fade effect as one of its parameter, and not as the value of some registry key.

Comment: The option is still in Win7, but unchecking it stopped menu fading, but didn't change the disappearing arrows.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try to disable visual themes for eclipse:

- right click on eclipse.exe and preferences
- Compatibility mode and check Disable visual themes

thats it

Comment: Yes! Best answer, takes the whole app back to XP look - tree views have + icons and dotted lines again.

Comment: This does not seem to work with the 64 bit executable on Windows 7 (64-bit).

Answer (score 2):

Will be "fixed" with Eclipse 3.8 (although it's an OS issue). https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=342282

Comment: If you're interested in the patched JAR for Eclipse 3.7.1 or 3.7.2 let me know.

Answer (score 1):

My Eclipse started showing this behaviour when I moved to Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this — very — irritating annoyance too, in Eclipse Helios, on Windows 7 Pro.

In the Prefs of Eclipse, I had the tree triangles always coming and going and coming and going.

**I have solved the problem, without touching to Eclipse.**

I went to :

*Control Panel* → *Personnalisation*

And I chose the theme *Windows Classic*.

It's a bit grey, but **in Eclipse the tree triangles are now signs “+” and they don't disappear anymore**.

**Note :** To make this solution to work in Eclipse Indigo, I had to quit & relaunch Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

This is Vista (and Windows 7, I guess) behavior. You can see it in Windows Explorer too. This is not an Eclipse issue.