# How to display dotted lines in eclipse project explorer?

Tags: eclipse, ide

See these two images of eclipse project explorer below. The first one has dotted lines (so it's much easier to see the hierarchy), while the second one does not (which is the case for the eclipse on my computer).

How to configure eclipse 3.6 on Windows 7 to display dotted lines?

[image: with dotted lines][image: without dotted lines]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 7 removed this tree-view component from application usage, you can read about it here.

http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/25956-windows-explorer-tree-view-connecting-lines.html

In otherwords, you can't add it back, but that link provides a modification which they claim helps out a bit.

It was called "Simple Folder View", you can read about how it was turned on/off in Vista.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Change-folder-views-and-behavior

Comment: A little bit surprised to know this Java application uses this native windows component. Another reason for sticking with Netbeans.

Comment: @powerboy This is actually the reason why many of us prefer SWT over Swing: you are guarantied to comply with the native look 'n feel.. ;-)

Comment: The tree-view with dotted line is still available (with Aero theme), for example in _regedit_ or _Device Manager_ (see [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/iJN4Y9q.png)).

Answer (score 0):

You can make the whole app go back to an XP like look by disabling visual themes on the compatibility settings. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8973912/381161

Comment: This does not seem to work with the 64 bit version (tested on Windows 7 64 bit).